# Tableau not exporting all rows in CSV

Tags: csv, export, tableau-api

I working with Tableau 10.5 and have loaded an Excel fill with ~30.000 rows. On the "Data Source" tab, only ~25.000 show up.
While the sums of the values are correct in Tableau, I am getting only ~25.000 rows and incorrect sums (the values are too small) when exporting the data to a csv.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have a filter on the data source or on the extract?

Comment: I am filtering on the different sheets, but on the "Data Source" sheet I am not applying any filters